# Cant find package from $GOROOT and $GOPATH

Tags: go, gopath

Small part of error I'm getting after trying to run go build command

```
go build ./...
trillian.pb.go:7:8: cannot find package "github.com/golang/protobuf/proto" in any of:
    /usr/local/go/src/github.com/golang/protobuf/proto (from $GOROOT)
    /Projects/Proj1/trillian/src/github.com/golang/protobuf/proto (from $GOPATH)

trillian.pb.go:11:8: cannot find package "github.com/golang/protobuf/ptypes/any" in any of:
    /usr/local/go/src/github.com/golang/protobuf/ptypes/any (from $GOROOT)
    /Projects/Proj1/trillian/src/github.com/golang/protobuf/ptypes/any (from $GOPATH)

trillian_admin_api.pb.go:12:8: cannot find package "github.com/golang/protobuf/ptypes/empty" in any of:
    /usr/local/go/src/github.com/golang/protobuf/ptypes/empty (from $GOROOT)
    /Projects/Proj1/trillian/src/github.com/golang/protobuf/ptypes/empty (from $GOPATH)

trillian.pb.go:10:8: cannot find package "github.com/google/trillian/crypto/sigpb" in any of:
    /usr/local/go/src/github.com/google/trillian/crypto/sigpb (from $GOROOT)
    /Projects/Proj1/trillian/src/github.com/google/trillian/crypto/sigpb (from $GOPATH)

trillian_admin_api.pb.gw.go:17:2: cannot find package "github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway/runtime" in any of:
    /usr/local/go/src/github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway/runtime (from  $GOROOT)
    /Projects/Proj1/trillian/src/github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway/runtime (from $GOPATH)

trillian_admin_api.pb.gw.go:18:2: cannot find package "github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway/utilities" in any of:
    /usr/local/go/src/github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway/utilities (from $GOROOT)
    /Projects/Proj1/trillian/src/github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway/utilities (from $GOPATH)

trillian_admin_api.pb.go:15:2: cannot find package "golang.org/x/net/context" in any of:
    /usr/local/go/src/golang.org/x/net/context (from $GOROOT)
    /Projects/Proj1/trillian/src/golang.org/x/net/context (from $GOPATH)

trillian_admin_api.pb.go:10:8: cannot find package "google.golang.org/genproto/googleapis/api/annotations" in any of:
    /usr/local/go/src/google.golang.org/genproto/googleapis/api/annotations (from $GOROOT)
    /Projects/Proj1/trillian/src/google.golang.org/genproto/googleapis/api/annotations (from $GOPATH)

trillian_log_api.pb.go:65:8: cannot find package "google.golang.org/genproto/googleapis/rpc/status" in any of:
    /usr/local/go/src/google.golang.org/genproto/googleapis/rpc/status (from $GOROOT)
    /Projects/Proj1/trillian/src/google.golang.org/genproto/googleapis/rpc/status (from $GOPATH)

trillian_admin_api.pb.go:11:8: cannot find package "google.golang.org/genproto/protobuf/field_mask" in any of:
    /usr/local/go/src/google.golang.org/genproto/protobuf/field_mask (from $GOROOT)
    /Projects/Proj1/trillian/src/google.golang.org/genproto/protobuf/field_mask (from $GOPATH)
```

Go env output

```
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN=""
GOEXE=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="linux"
GOOS="linux"
GOPATH="/Projects/Proj1/trillian"
GORACE=""
GOROOT="/usr/local/go"
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64"
CC="gcc"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/tmp/go-build690359699=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches"
CXX="g++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
```

`GOPATH` and `GOROOT` are set but still can't run the command without errors. Tried installing to home and custom directories changing gopath and goroot regardless but still no luck. Any suggestions how to solve this?

Comment: Have you installed protobuf? Type `go get -u github.com/golang/protobuf/{proto,protoc-gen-go}` to install !

Comment: Same error if i try to use that command

Comment: Same error?When `go install` or when `go build` after `go install`?

Answer (score 12):

All the packages imported are looked in under GOROOT and GOPATH environment variables first. Make sure your package is somewhere under these directories.

Now Suppose **GOPATH** is set to : /Users/test/Desktop/GoProject

and *GOROOT* : /usr/local/go (where go is installed)
. If a file in your GoProject has a package imported as

```
import "abc/def/packageName"
```

then it should be present at any of the below two places:

**/Users/test/Desktop/GoProject**/src/abc/def/packageName/*
*/usr/local/go*/src/abc/def/packageName/*

If not, you will get error as reported in the question.

The files inside these directories will have the first line as

```
package packageName
```

stating that all these files constitutes a package **packageName**

Answer (score 5):

As the official document says:

> The simplest way is to run `go get -u github.com/golang/protobuf/{proto,protoc-gen-go}`.

See full introduction here :[golang/protobuf installation](https://github.com/golang/protobuf#installation).

Comment: Maybe you have installed `protoc`,protoc is the compiler for `.proto` files, not golang packages i f you want to use protobuf package, install it using `go get` from `Github`!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to have a version of go `1.11+`.

Older versions do not support modules, thus they fail to download what's needed leading to the `Can't find package from $GOROOT and $GOPATH` problem.

Comment: With Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS, I followed [these steps](https://tecadmin.net/install-go-on-ubuntu/) and the problem vanished.

Answer (score 0):

I installed *go get -u github.com/golang/protobuf/{proto,protoc-gen-go}*, in my terminal

Then did a *go mod init example.com/filename*, this created a go mod file and removed the error for me.

Answer (score 0):

I used Go 1.20 and my project is at ~/DSBSystems.
 Below are the steps I ran:

- go env -w GO111MODULE=on
- cd ~/DSBSystems
- go mod init DSBSystems
- go build ....

Answer (score 0):

go to your main.go directory and run `go get -u .` It will download all the packages that is required for your code based on the go.mod file

Answer (score 0):

try to use this command in terminal : `go mod tidy`

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?

Answer (score 0):

Adding a `go.work` file fixed the issue for me since I'm running an app with several `go` projects. This was necessary to get it to work in VSCode. GoLand didn't have this problem and worked without the `go.work` file