# Go and paths are rough. Help is appreciated

Tags: go

Okay well I think Im finally stuck on trying things without some more ideas or help. Im attempting to use 

 https://github.com/billgraziano/go-windows-svc/blob/master/cmd/gosvc/main.go. 
I cloned it over and made adjusted to where the read me states. This is suppose to spin up a service. The service is running what we will cal the DCA which is something that spins up a server.So I haven't even started debugging other issues on that end. The issue is when trying to do a build I get

PS C:\Users\rutger\go\src\go-windows-svc\cmd\gosvc> go build main.go

```
main.go:10:2: cannot find package "bitbucket.org/somepalce/go-dca-base/cmd/dca-agent/main.go" in any of:
        c:\go\src\bitbucket.org\someplace\go-dca-base\cmd\dca-agent\main.go (from $GOROOT)
        C:\Users\rutger\go\src\bitbucket.org\somepalce\go-dca-base\cmd\dca-agent\main.go (from $GOPATH)
```

this is the main from his program but the first import is adjusted relative to where my go path is. 
package main

```
import (
    "bitbucket.org/someplace/go-dca-base/cmd/dca-agent/main.go"
    "github.com/pkg/errors"
)
```

File structure of windows service project

```
C:\USERS\RUTGER\GO\SRC\GO-WINDOWS-SVC
├───app
└───cmd
    └───gosvc
          -- (has the main)
```

File structure for DCA

```
C:\USERS\RUTGER\GO\SRC\BITBUCKET.ORG\SOMEPLACE\GO-DCA-BASE\CMD\DCA-AGENT
├───cmd
       -- (has main for DCA)
├───compile
└───logs
```

PS C:\Users\rutger\go\src\go-windows-svc\cmd\gosvc> go build main.go
main.go:10:2: cannot find package "bitbucket.org/somepalce/go-dca-base/cmd/dca-agent/main.go" in any of:
        c:\go\src\bitbucket.org\somepalce\go-dca-base\cmd\dca-agent\main.go (from $GOROOT)
        C:\Users\rutger\go\src\bitbucket.org\somepalce\go-dca-base\cmd\dca-agent\main.go (from $GOPATH)
PS C:\Users\rutger\go\src\go-windows-svc\cmd\gosvc>

Output of go env
PS C:\Users\rutger\go\src\go-windows-svc\cmd\gosvc> go env

```
set GOARCH=amd64
set GOBIN=
set GOCACHE=C:\Users\rutger\AppData\Local\go-build
set GOEXE=.exe
set GOFLAGS=
set GOHOSTARCH=amd64
set GOHOSTOS=windows
set GOOS=windows
set GOPATH=C:\Users\rutger\go
set GOPROXY=
set GORACE=
set GOROOT=c:\go
set GOTMPDIR=
set GOTOOLDIR=c:\go\pkg\tool\windows_amd64
set GCCGO=gccgo
set CC=gcc
set CXX=g++
set CGO_ENABLED=1
set GOMOD=
set CGO_CFLAGS=-g -O2
set CGO_CPPFLAGS=
set CGO_CXXFLAGS=-g -O2
set CGO_FFLAGS=-g -O2
set CGO_LDFLAGS=-g -O2
set PKG_CONFIG=pkg-config
set GOGCCFLAGS=-m64 -mthreads -fno-caret-diagnostics -Qunused-arguments -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=C:\Users\rutger\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build634488178=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches
```

Ive read other questions form stack and their req's like: \n

[Cant find package from $GOROOT and $GOPATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43325013/cant-find-package-from-goroot-and-gopath) \n

https://forum.golangbridge.org/t/go-build-cant-find-package/11880/10 \n

[Cant find package from $GOROOT and $GOPATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43325013/cant-find-package-from-goroot-and-gopath?rq=1)

So ya any help is appreciated. I wouldnt think adding in a vendor would have any issues since all the paths seem fine.

Comment: Have you done something like “go get” in order to downloads the packages named by the import paths?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your import of `bitbucket.org/printtrackerpro/go-dca-base/cmd/dca-agent/main.go` is invalid, for two reasons:

- In Go you import *packages*, not *files*
- You cannot import the `main` package at all, because `main` is the program's entry point and cyclic dependencies are not permitted

Comment: Thanks. I did think that was an issue at first. However when I try to import it one level up. In this case the dca-agent. Its states that it is a program. Sorry for my ignorance in not understanding Go.

Comment: Yes - that would be the second point in my answer. You cannot import a `main` package. It is the starting point of your program, the start of the import graph, and the import graph cannot contain any circular dependencies (a imports b, b imports c, c imports a).

Comment: Also your command `go build main.go` is incorrect - like imports, you build *packages*, not *files*. So you can `go build .` if you're in the directory of your `main` package.